# Why saving lmer plot doesn't work in a for loop

Tags: r

This is really strange. Say we have a `lmer` model. The code for producing diagnostic plot works without any problem, but when I put it in the for loop, it stops working!! It simply produces an empty plot:

```
require(lme4)
m <- lmer(y ~ (1|x), data = data.frame(y = c(1,1,1,1), x = c("a", "a", "b", "b")))

for (i in 1:2) {
    # this code works only outside the for-loop!
    png(filename = paste0(i, ".png")) 
    plot(m)
    dev.off()
}
```

The code normally produces correct PNG file if it is run outside of the for loop! This is really strange. Where is the problem?

Comment: My guess would be because the plot method for that package is using either ggplot2 or lattice graphics, and so the plots need to be explicitly printed?

Comment: @joran is right ... a cheap way of determining if `png` etc will work on a plot method is to plot it normally (`plot(m)`), and try `locator(1)` on it; if you get `Error in locator(1): plot.new has not been called yet`, that means it is not base-graphics, so you'll need a different method to save the plot.

Comment: Yep, the docs say that it's using lattice graphics.

Comment: @joran Good guess, `print(plot(m))` solved it.

Comment: Is there (other than cheap way and ... err, reading the docs) another way of determining programmatically the type of active plot?

Comment: @r2evans that sounds worthy of being its own question.

Comment: Aha... thanks guys. But why doesn't this code work for lattice plots? Saving plots should work for any plots right?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f

Comment: @TMS Because `plot()` doesn't actually draw the plot (for lattice or ggplot). It creates an object that has the data for the plot. It doesn't get drawn till the resulting object is `print()`ed. When you are working interactively in the console, all your results are automatically `print()`ed. This is not true in a `for()` loop.

Comment: To answer my own comment-question a little bit: `class(plot(m))` returns `"trellis"`, and with a little sleuthing that eventually resolves to use `lattice::print.trellis`. (Though I find it a little odd that `class(plot(m))`, which should not be rendering any graphic, actually *does* open up a graphic window, even if nothing is displayed. Odd.)

Comment: @Gregor, you're absolutely right, I should know better :-)

Comment: @MrFlick aha!!! Wow!!! Makes sense! This is really confusing, I know this behaviour for `print`ing text to the console, and I didn't know that this plotting occurs via `print`ing.. pretty confusing :) MrFlick, this explanation is worth to be an answer I think.

Comment: @TMS, same thing for `ggplot2`-produced graphics; in a loop (and often in Rmarkdown docs), `print(p)` is required.

Comment: So a common name for interactive command line interfaces (not just in R) is a "REPL", which stands for read-eval-print loop. Every command you type at the interactive console is read, evaluated and then the results are automatically printed.

Comment: @joran, well, "printed" - plotting is suprisingly done via printing. And then there is the inconsistency that for normal plots, `plot()` function is just directly plotting, whereas for these "lattice" plots, it is just returning a value that might or might not be printed (=> plotted)...

Comment: Right, sorry, I just meant that the printing is actually always happening when working interactively (even with a base R plot), whatever is returned (potentially nothing) is printed at the console.

Comment: @joran, not necessarily "at the console"! :-)

Comment: @MrFlick **marked as duplicate** OMG, that's my own question!!! :-o Ha ha :-D

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by that, but I also feel like I haven't explained myself very well, so it could be we're just talking past each other.

Comment: @TMS I didn't even notice that. Since that answer is basically the same just for a different function, it makes sense just to make it as a dup. Have you learned nothing in the past 6 years?! :)

Comment: @MrFlick :-D lol :-D I have learnt so much man... :-) So much that I sweetly forgot about the pains and gotchas of lattice :-)